# convert query from Postresql to Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Hi i have asked a question about [how to transfer the sql code from Postgresql to Mysql.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68973670/convert-postgresql-to-mysql)
Thanks to the kindly help i am now able to create the table. Now i have a following question of the query to transfer again from Postgresql to Mysql.

Create the table

```
CREATE TABLE public.`user` (
    id varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    chat_id varchar(10) NULL,
    state INT NOT NULL,
    create_time timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    update_time timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The query i'd like to transfer to mysql:
After insert a row of data, check if id has conflict. if we get a conflict we update chat_id  and state

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO public.`user`
(id, chat_id, state)
VALUES(%s, %s, 1)
ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE
SET chat_id = EXCLUDED.chat_id, state = EXCLUDED.state;
'''
```

Comment: You could always just take a few minutes and check out the MySQL manual. So do a quick search in google for `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL's `ON CONFLICT` is close to MySQL's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

But your query do the next: if entered `id` value is absent in the table then the row is inserted, if it is present then old row state is preserved. For to do the same in MySQL you may use more simple

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO public.`user` (id, chat_id, state)
VALUES(%s, %s, 1);
```

I.e. if some error (including duplicate violation) detected then simply ignore the values to be inserted. Pay attention - any error, not only duplicate violation, will be ignored.

If it is not safe for you then use ODKU:

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO public.`user` (id, chat_id, state)
VALUES(%s, %s, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id;
```

In MySQL in ODKU clause only explicitly updated columns values are altered (rather than ON CONFLICT) - so `id` reassign to the same value is an analog of "ignore new values". Of course you may use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  chat_id=chat_id, state=state`, no difference.